# Passing function to Angular directive with template parameter

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am having trouble using a parameter in my template for a function that I have passed into a directive with isolate scope. The directive uses the template in which I am calling the function but for some reason my parameter "meetpunt" is undefined:

my template where meetpunt seems to be undefined when I debug the getCoordinaten function:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="meetpunt in meetpunten">
     <td>{{getCoordinaten(meetpunt)}}</td>
 </tr>
```

my directive:

```
angular.module('zendantennesApp').directive('meetpuntTabel', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'views/components/meetpunt-tabel/meetpunt-tabel.html',
        scope: {
            single: '@',
            meetpunten: '=',
            getCoordinaten: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        }
    }
});
```

my controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('zendantennesApp')
    .controller('MeetpuntTabelCtrl', function ($scope) {


        $scope.getCoordinaten = function (meetpunt) {
            return '(' + meetpunt.geometry.coordinates[0] + ', ' + meetpunt.geometry.coordinates[1] + ')';
        };


    });
```

this is how I am calling the directive:

```
<section ng-controller='MeetpuntTabelCtrl'><meetpunt-tabel meetpunten='meetpunten' get-coordinaten='getCoordinaten(meetpunt)' single='true'></meetpunt-tabel></section>
```

any help would be appreciated. 
kind regards

Comment: Shouldn't you use `$parent` because you are in a `ng-repeat`? `$parent.getCoordinaten(meetpunt)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To pass a local argument to an expression function of  `"@"`, you need to pass a hash-map of argument name-values. For illustration, I'll use a slightly different name:

```
{{getCoordinaten({foo: meetpunt})}}
```

Then, when then directive is being used, `foo` (the key) becomes the local variable to that expression, which a user of the directive can pass to his own function:

```
<meetpunt-tabel get-coordinaten="getCoordinaten(foo)"...>
```

(Of course, you'd want to name it `meetpunt` instead of `foo`)

Comment: yep that did the trick. thank you. makes total sense when I think of it as a key that is passed.

Comment: @Arno_Geismar, as an aside, you should know that it's not the best idea to have a function call in an expression, `{{doSomething()}}`, because this expression is executed on **every** digest cycle. While, in your case, the function is simple, which is good, it is also outside of your directive, so a user of your directive may inadvertently make the function more complicated... perhaps, consider re-factoring some things

Comment: yeah am refactoring as we speak, I took a different approach. Thank you for the clear answer

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set the controller inside your directive? And use the "controller as" syntax?

*your main view*

```
<section>
   <meetpunt-tabel meetpunten='meetpunten' single='true'>
   </meetpunt-tabel>
</section>
```

*directive code*

```
angular.module('zendantennesApp').directive('meetpuntTabel', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'views/components/meetpunt-tabel/meetpunt-tabel.html',
        scope: {
            single: '@',
            meetpunten: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        }
        controller: function(){
            this.getCoordinaten = function (meetpunt) {
                return '(' + meetpunt.geometry.coordinates[0] + ', ' + meetpunt.geometry.coordinates[1] + ')';
        };
        },
        controllerAs: 'meetPuntCtrl'
    }
});
```

*template*

```
 <tr ng-repeat="meetpunt in meetpunten">
     <td>{{meetPuntCtrl.getCoordinaten(meetpunt)}}</td>
 </tr>
```

**Explanations :**

- ng-controller, ng-repeat, and your directive are all creating a new isolated scope. Having so much isolated scopes for almost no reason (your sample was short) will make the $digest cycle longer.
- Using the "controller as" syntax makes it easier to make sure you are using the intended scope.