# Undefined Passing $event to function from angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying pass `$event` context to function at controller, but receive undefined param

My code:

```
directive('setting', function() {
 return {
  restrict: 'E',
  template: `
    <div class='dropdown setting'>
        <button type='button'>
            {{getSettingHTML($event)}}
        </button>
    </div>

};
```

and my controller function:

```
 $scope.getSettingHTML = function(e) {
   console.log(e);
 };

 // return e == undefined
```

With `{{getSettingHTML('xxx')}}` I got right string.

How can I get the target which call to function?

Thanks!

Comment: please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645392/passing-function-to-angular-directive-with-template-parameter)

Comment: switch $event with prop

Comment: Hi @Tùng, ng-click đó mình bắt được event rồi, đó là 1 function khác, còn func kia là **getSettingHTML** thì nó báo lỗi **undefined**, và hàm đó mình  gọi bằng expression **{{getSettingHTML($event)}}**, không thông qua 1 action như **ng-click, ng-mous...** nào

Comment: @NhạHoàng theo mình biết thì cái $event nay nó chỉ có khi làm các action như click , mouse , .. thôi . Cái $event này chứa object $event của browser

Comment: `$event` is not just some variable that always exist. It is created when an event happens, for example the `ng-click`. I think you should make your question clearer; what are you trying to achieve? What do you want to do with the `$event`? What do you expect it to be?

Comment: @Tùng, mình hiểu vấn đề rồi, $event tồn tại khi 1 action xảy ra

Comment: @devqon Thank you, I got the problem, $event was created when any action fire

Answer (score 1):

Where is this $event coming from? a click on the button? If so, then the $event is going to be the first argument of an onClick event, like this:

```
<button ng-click="getSettingHTML($event)">click me!</button>
```

Comment: Hi @jperelli, it comes from expression **{{getSettingHTML($event)}}**, it works fine with any action like **ng-click**